# What are the number of real solutions (x,y) of the system : $3^x +4^y=13 $ and $\log_3(x)-\log_4(y)=1$

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find number of solutions $(x,y)$ for :

$$\begin{align} 3^x +4^y &=13 \\ \log_3(x)-\log_4(y)&=1\end{align} $$

At first I tried :

$$\log_3(x)=1+\log_4(y)$$

and then :

$x=3^{\log_4(4y)}$

in the end : $3^{3^{\log_4(4y)}} +4^y =13$.

I am trying to find if this has a unique solution but i am stuck here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\log_4(x) - \log_4(y)=1$? That would be much easier to solve, *and* the solution comes out nice.

Comment: no it is not like that

Comment: See this [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764479/what-are-the-number-of-real-solutions-x-y-of-the-system-3x-4x-13-and?noredirect=1) from the OP

Comment: the original question was mine and i deleted and asked again

Comment: Would you like a possible series solution to the equation? This would use [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Lagrange%20reversion,of%20compositions%20with%20such%20functions.&text=Then%20for%20any%20function%20g%2C%20for%20small%20enough%20y%3A&text=In%20which%20case%20the%20equation%20can%20be%20derived%20using%20perturbation%20theory.)

Comment: yes would be great

Answer (score 3):

In order to find the number of solutions of a problem with these constraints we firstly try to write each constraint in the style of functions:
A:
$$
3^x + 4^y = 13 \Rightarrow y = \log_4 (13-3^x) = f(x)
$$
B:
$$
\log_3 (x) - log_4 (y) = 1 \Rightarrow y = 4^{log_3(x) - 1} = g(x)
$$

for any solution we have:
$$
4^{log_3(x) - 1} = \log_4 (13-3^x) \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x)
$$
clearly the function $g(x)$ is strictly increasing with an infimum of 0. and the function $f(x)$ is clearly strictly decreasing with a supremum of $\log_4 (13) > 0$ since any strictly increasing or strictly decreasing function is one-to-one, for any value of y in the range of f(x) and g(x)there is exactly one solution to $y = f(\alpha)$ and $y = g(\beta)$.
Now first suppose there is no solution. that means only one thing : $$\alpha \neq \beta$$ this means that $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$ has no solution for $h(x) = 0$ but since $g(x)$ is strictly increasing and $-f(x)$ is strictly increasing, $h(x)$ is strictly increasing too. but we know that the minimum of h(x) is certainly less than zero(can you say why?). and since h(x) is also one-to-one that means there is exactly one solution for $h(x)=0$ therefore, the problem has exactly one solution.

Comment: why h(x) is certainly less than zero?

Comment: its minimum is less than zero because we know that since it is strictly increasing and its domains infimum is zero and the function is continuous we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} h(x) = 0 - \log_4 12 < 0$ and its minimum occurs at the aforementioned limit.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-We have
$$\log_3(x)-\log_4(y)=1\iff\log_{3}(x)-\frac{\log_3(y)}{\log_3(4)}=\log_3(3)$$ then by injectivity of logaritms one has, putting $a=\log_3(4)$,
$$x= 3y^{\dfrac 1a}$$ so the resultant equation $$27^{y^{\frac 1a}}+4^y=13$$ it is a trascendental equation which leads to the approximate solution $\boxed{(x,y)=(2.14,0.65)}$